# How should I write an expectation for a 401 redirect?

Tags: rspec

```
#excerpt
subject { response }
its(:response_code){ should eq 401 }
it { should redirect_to '/sign_in' }
```

This returns:

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET #edit when not signed in should redirect to "/sign_in"
     Failure/Error: it { should redirect_to '/sign_in' }
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <401>
```

I thought a 401 was a redirect? Or does rspec's redirect_to method specifically look for a 302?

Comment: Doesn't the [401](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) response code mean Unauthorized?

Comment: So what happens when someone wants to access a restricted area and gets redirected somewhere else because they're unauthorized? Should that redirect be a normal 302 despite the fact they're being redirected because they're unauthorized? When do I give them a 401?